# Segmentation fault while installing Python 3.5: ensurepip

Tags: python, segmentation-fault

I got a segmentation fault while trying to install Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 21.10.

```
$ guettli@p15:~$ pyenv install 3.5.8

Downloading Python-3.5.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.8/Python-3.5.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.5.8...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 21.10 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20211119144903.305257
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20211119144903.305257.log

Last 10 log lines:
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The same happens, when I install Python-3.5.10.tar.xz (without pyenv). What can I do now?

Version: Ubuntu 21.10
Output of `configure`: https://pastebin.com/rie17s8Z
Output of `make`: https://pastebin.com/F3C4evR6
Output of `make install`: https://paste2.org/LKxHUYkM

With PYTHONFAULTHANDLER:

```
guettli@p15:~/Downloads/Python-3.5.10$ PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 LANG=C python3.5 -m ensurepip
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007fb703b40740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 276 in _reset_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 541 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/uuid.py", line 464 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/tmp/tmppx73eqwt/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 4 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/tmp/tmppx73eqwt/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/request.py", line 7 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/tmp/tmppx73eqwt/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 41 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/tmp/tmppx73eqwt/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1015 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/tmp/tmppx73eqwt/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 943 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 943 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/tmp/tmppx73eqwt/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 62 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 943 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 943 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 943 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/tmp/tmppx73eqwt/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 21 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 40 in _run_pip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 116 in bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 209 in _main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4 in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85 in _run_code
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193 in _run_module_as_main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: @user535733 in above output you see the last ten lines of the output. There is nothing which looks relevant in the lines above these ten lines.

Comment: @guetti, indeed. But that begs the question *why is a shell script being output to your log?* Look at more than the last 10 lines.

Comment: Is there anything unique to your installation? I've installed 3.5.10 (via the `.tar.xz`) on a 20.04 an a 21.04 installation in a virtual machine without complaint. Not sure what might be preventing you from installing this specific version ...

Comment: I suspect that some dependencies for building this version of Python are not compatible with Ubuntu 21.10. Do you need version 3.5.8? Can't you use a more modern version like 3.8?. I would try if it work in a Docker container with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: @CarlesMateo the same error happens if I use Python 3.5.10. Unfortunately I need Python 3.5 for this case.

Comment: you might want to be aware that modern Django does not work properly on Python 3.5 - so if you're stuck on old django which has a lot of security holes you have a larger problem here.

Comment: i've installed 3.5.8 via the .tar.xz without complaint. probably you need `echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri did you do this on Ubuntu 21.10?

Comment: @guettli i'm on 20.04

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution here: https://giters.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1889

Step 1: create file segfault.patch with the following contents:

```
--- Include/objimpl.h
+++ Include/objimpl.h
@@ -250,7 +250,7 @@
         union _gc_head *gc_prev;
         Py_ssize_t gc_refs;
     } gc;
-    double dummy;  /* force worst-case alignment */
+    long double dummy;  /* force worst-case alignment */
 } PyGC_Head;

 extern PyGC_Head *_PyGC_generation0;
--- Objects/obmalloc.c
+++ Objects/obmalloc.c
@@ -643,8 +643,8 @@
  *
  * You shouldn't change this unless you know what you are doing.
  */
-#define ALIGNMENT               8               /* must be 2^N */
-#define ALIGNMENT_SHIFT         3
+#define ALIGNMENT               16               /* must be 2^N */
+#define ALIGNMENT_SHIFT         4

 /* Return the number of bytes in size class I, as a uint. */
 #define INDEX2SIZE(I) (((uint)(I) + 1) << ALIGNMENT_SHIFT)
```

Step 2: apply the patch:

```
user@host:Python-3.5.10$ patch -p0 < segfault.patch
```

Step 3:

```
user@host:Python-3.5.10$ make -j 8  # adapt to your number of CPU cores
```

Step 4:

Either:

```
user@host:Python-3.5.10$ sudo make altinstall  # if you want only python3.6
```

Or

```
user@host:Python-3.5.10$ sudo make install  # if you want systemwide python as well
```

Comment: i'm already on Impish. i tried it, a voted to awesome answered.

Comment: Almost give up. Your patch worked for Python 3.6.15 in Kubuntu 21.10. Although I've already installed it from source, I made the patch, executed `make && sudo make altinstall` and now `python3.6 -m pip list` doesn't return a segmentation fault, thanks. Upvoted!

Comment: You've saved my hair! Worked with vanilla python 3.6.15 on ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: Also works in Python 3.5.9 using an alpine v3.17.2 VM! Before, `pyenv install 3.7.9` was failing on `./python -c 'import ctypes'`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently it's enough to set `CC=gcc-10` before building Python 3.5 and 3.6 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, as per the [pyenv issue](https://giters.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1889):

```
sudo apt install gcc-10
CC=gcc-10 pyenv install 3.6.13
```

(I'm not using Pyenv myself, but compiling from source, and this workaround fixed the segfaults for me.)

Answer (score 2):

## Miniconda

I suggest installing miniconda to manage your virtual environment and installing the desired python version within the newly created env.

In my opinion, it's a decent solutions not as bloated as anaconda and you can still use pip, poetry or whatever package management software that you would like.

Comment: Short and useful

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and got the same error; also tried 3.5.10 the best in this release line and still the same. I assumed it was a problem with pyenv and tried 2.2.0 but still the same result.
So I downloaded Python 3.5.8 and proceeded to install manually (at the install directory, see Python [docs](https://devguide.python.org/setup/)) with:

`./configure --with-pydebug --enable-optimizations --with-lto`

`make`

But in `make` the python got hung up on testing the distribution. So the advice is don't use any options with `./configure`.
Then run:

`make`

`sudo make install` or `sudo make altinstall`

There is more than one problem in this build 3.5.8 of which the main reason why pyenv doesn't work seems to be due to this:

`/home/<me>/Python-3.5.8/Modules/nismodule.c:17:10: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory 17 | #include <rpc/rpc.h>`

Then use Pycharm to build you project or simply use venv or virtulenv.

Comment: Thank you for reproducing it. Unfortunately I still get the seg-fault, even if I use a newly extracted sources and don't provide any options to `configure`. It happens during `sudo make altinstall`, too.

Comment: @guettli could you give more info: what you did exactly, and the output? It could be that 3.5.8 has a fatal bug in the build but I can still produce an executable.

Comment: you said that you can reproduce the error. Nice. I don't do anything special. Just untar, configure, make, sudo make install. I uploaded the logs of each step to the question.