# ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging'

Tags: python, pip, tox

I need to get some software running on Python 3.5

I am using Ubuntu 21.10.

I get this error:

```
(foobar_addressbook) guettli@p15:~/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook$ tox -e py35-django18 


py35-django18 create: /home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/log/py35-django18-1.log
==================================================================== log start =====================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.packaging'

===================================================================== log end ======================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________ summary ______________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   py35-django18: InvocationError for command /home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/bin/python -m pip freeze (exited with code 1)
```

Any idea how I can fix this error?

Related question: [Segmentation fault while installing Python 3.5: ensurepip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376525/segmentation-fault-while-installing-python-3-5-ensurepip)

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1

pip in the virtualenv seems broken, so bootstrap pip:

```
curl  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py | .tox/py35-django18/bin/python -
```

## Step 2

Now I get this error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xsbc7r69/django-celery_63fa83d5391f499a9cc375c1c1fed8b6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xsbc7r69/django-celery_63fa83d5391f499a9cc375c1c1fed8b6/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6esk_zf9
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xsbc7r69/django-celery_63fa83d5391f499a9cc375c1c1fed8b6/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "/home/guettli/foobar/projects/foobar_addressbook/.tox/py35-django18/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
    ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

To fix this:

```
.tox/py35-django18/bin/python -m pip install -U setuptools
```

Now the virtualenv of tox is working.

If you know an easier way to get Python3.5 working on Ubuntu 21.10, please leave a comment. Thank you.

Comment: The way to get Python ancient working on ubuntu 21.10 is to use PyENV to set it up, or make sure you install  PIP with your python compilation (not a default!) - this also makes setuptools and other things available in your environment by default.

Comment: @ThomasWard I tried pyenv first, but it failed with a seg fault. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376525/segmentation-fault-while-installing-python-3-5-ensurepip

Comment: May I ask why you *need* Python 3.5 which is many years old now?  Is updating your application for newer python not doable for some reason?

Comment: @ThomasWard Python3.5 is an intermediate step to get from 2.7 to 3.8. (This django app is using Django 1.4 at the moment).

Comment: As someone who's had to move from Django old to Django latest your 'intermediate' step is likely to cause you more grief than a total rewrite.  Because then you have to rewrite again to get to an even newer Django that is py3.8 compatible.

Comment: @ThomasWard I don't want to use PyENV. It does magic things which I don't want to be done. For example it changes PATH and it needs to be enabled via .profile. All I want is `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`. I don't need a tool to switch between Python versions.